# What are Points and How do I get them?

Tags: support, reputation, comments, asking-questions

I signed up for the Android Enthusiast because my tablet has gone goofy. Specifically chrome and firefox. However, I can't ask questions or comment until I have reputation points. But I don't see any way to get points, nor do I know what they are?

It seems the entire internet has lost their minds.

Please explains the points so I can get on with my questions?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need *reputation* (that's how we call it) to ask questions (or answer them); you can already do that at [1 reputation](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts). You do need [50 reputation](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) to comment.

You gain reputation by asking good questions or providing good answers; other community members can upvote them and you'll get 10 reputation for each upvote. Another common way (where I got most of my reputation from) is to [suggest edits](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/editing) to improve existing posts; if one of those edits is approved, you'll get 2 reputation.

For more information, see the Help Center article [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) or this FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/295232)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and that make sense. 

I could ask a question on the problem I'm seeing but I've already seen at least two other posts on it, and netiquette dictates that I use existing post/threads rather than recreating a new on that has already been addressed.

I have additional info on the problem but I can't comment on it to give the information. 

Most forums ask for you to RTFM and search before posting new question. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: @user339541 this is not a forum but Q&A site (question = problem, answer = solution) only if you know solution you can post it as answer. the comments section is for clarifying (side notes that have meta characteristic)